# Setting up equivalent of SQLMembershipProvider for ASP.NET vNext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

How do I go about setting up an equivalent of a  SQLMembershipProvider  for individual account authentication for a web app built using ASP.NET vNext.  Based on what I am reading, the authentication framework has changed.  I would appreciate if you can point me to some reading material on this.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind my question.  My SQL Server Explorer in VS 2015 RC had some refresh issues and so I was unable to see the new database right away.  In any event, the following link describes how to do it:

[Using Identity in ASP.NET vNext](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/wiki/Using-Identity-in-ASP.NET-applications)